# Jquery Anythingslider too much recursion error

Tags: c#, jquery

I am getting a too much recursion error on my main page.

```
too much recursion
 NUMPAD_SUBTRACT:109,PAGE_DOWN:34,PAGE_...|absolute|fixed)/.test(b.curCSS(this,
```

jquery-ui.min.js (line 11)

and another one that looks like this:

```
too much recursion
(function(){"use strict";Raphael.proto...e a(this).addClass(b)})}})})(jQuery);
```

jquery.wijmo-complete.1.1.4.min.js(line 23)

I have no idea how to fix this. Thanks :)

here is the javascript for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $(":input[type='text'],:input[type='password'],:input[type='textarea']").wijtextbox();
           $(".button").button();
           $("#slider").anythingSlider({               
               width: 1000,
               height: 300,
               toggleControls: true,
               startStopped: true,
               theme:'metallic'
           });

       });
   </script>
```

Comment: What is your initiation code with the Anything slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from the mwEmbed-player. Thanks for the help :)